# Fatal Exception : Async Task #1 with geocoder

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, geocoding

may i know how can i solve this problem?
i get Fatal Exception : Asynctask #1 when i press the Calculate button 
[image: the screen shot of the app]
then my app straight away crashed. 
did i miss something for the asynctask? 
here is my mainactivity.java code

```
  package com.ccsy.mtravel;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Locale;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Geocoder;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            private EditText StartAdd;
            private EditText EndAdd;
            private Button calculate_Btn;
            private TextView totaldistance;
            private TextView totalamount;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            StartAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.StartAdd);
            EndAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EndAdd);
            totaldistance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totaldistance);
            totalamount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalamount);
            calculate_Btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate_Btn); 
            calculate_Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                    new SearchTask().execute(new String[] {StartAdd.getText().toString(), EndAdd.getText().toString()});
                            }
                    });

             if (!Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                calculate_Btn.setEnabled(false);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Geocoder methods getFromLocation and getFromLocationName are not implemented", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        private class SearchTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> {

                    @Override
                    protected List<Address> doInBackground(String... params) {
                        List<Address> addresses = null;
                        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                        try {
                            Address StartAdd = geocoder.getFromLocationName(params[0], 1).get(0);
                            Address EndAdd = geocoder.getFromLocationName(params[1], 1).get(0);

                            double StartAdd_Latitude = StartAdd.getLatitude();
                            double StartAdd_Longitude = StartAdd.getLongitude();

                            double EndAdd_Latitude = EndAdd.getLatitude();
                            double EndAdd_Longitude = EndAdd.getLongitude();

                            Location StartLocation = new Location("Starting_Point");
                            StartLocation.setLatitude(StartAdd_Latitude);
                            StartLocation.setLongitude(StartAdd_Longitude);

                            Location EndLocation = new Location("Ending_Point");
                            EndLocation.setLatitude(EndAdd_Latitude);
                            EndLocation.setLongitude(EndAdd_Longitude);

                            float distance = StartLocation.distanceTo(EndLocation);
                            totaldistance.setText(String.valueOf(distance));
                            double amount = distance * 1;
                            totalamount.setText(String.valueOf(amount));


                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return addresses;
                    }


            }



    }
```

and here is my log cat

```
    12-03 23:04:08.196: W/dalvikvm(7142): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41960700)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6804)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1077)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:358)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7646)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4446)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4283)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4258)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at com.ccsy.mtravel.MainActivity$SearchTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:78)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at com.ccsy.mtravel.MainActivity$SearchTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-03 23:04:08.206: E/AndroidRuntime(7142):     ... 4 more
12-03 23:04:08.546: W/dalvikvm(7142): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41960700)
12-03 23:04:08.546: I/Process(7142): Sending signal. PID: 7142 SIG: 9
```

thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 4):

> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

You can not modify the UI/views from within the `doInBackground` method. Use `onPostExecute` or `onProgressUpdate` or some kind of handler...

Please read [the AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), especially the topic **4 steps** to see which method will be invoked on the UI thread.